# Creating a Debian package that does not remove directories after it's purged

Tags: linux, debian, packaging, dpkg

I'm trying to create a Debian package that doesn't delete an empty directory after it's purged. Specifically, I'm creating my own package containing some CA certificates I trust.

I'm following Debian's suggested method of installing the certificates to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`. The problem I'm running in to is that the `ca-certificates` package creates `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` when it's installed and I'd like that directory to stick around when my package is purged.

My goal is to install my trust chain into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mychain` but when my Debian package is removed I want dpkg to *not* remove `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` if it's empty since the `ca-certificates` package explicitly created that directory.

I searched around for a definitive answer but all I managed to find were long forum posts and e-mail threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `postrm` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

case "$1" in
  purge|remove|upgrade|failed-upgrade|abort-install|abort-upgrade|disappear)
    # Recreate the /usr/local/share/ca-certificates directory, since we are
    # ignoring Debian Policy by intentionally installing here. Removal of
    # ca-certificates-local removes this directory if empty.
    if [ ! -e /usr/local/share/ca-certificates ]; then
        if mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates 2>/dev/null; then
            chown root:staff /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
            chmod 2775 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
        fi
    fi
;;

*)
    echo "postrm called with unknown argument \`$1'" >&2
    exit 1
;;
esac

#DEBHELPER#

exit 0
```

This code is from [ca-certificates-local](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ca-certificates/tree/master/examples/ca-certificates-local):

> This is an example stub source package that includes a dummy CA
>   certificate in the local/ directory. Remove the dummy certificate, copy
>   your trusted local root CA (in PEM format with the filename ending in
>   ".crt") to the local/ directory, edit files in the debian/ directory as
>   desired, and build your custom package.

See [README](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ca-certificates/blob/master/examples/ca-certificates-local/README), [Steps to build your custom local root CA package from this example](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ca-certificates/blob/master/examples/ca-certificates-local/README#L16)

So, the quick way to create and install such packages:

```
git clone git://anonscm.debian.org/collab-maint/ca-certificates.git ~/ca-certificates
cd ~/ca-certificates/examples/ca-certificates-local/
rm local/Local_Root_CA.crt
cp <path-to-your-cert> local/
# edit debian/control: change package-name, description, etc
# install build dependencies: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177505/how-to-install-parse-build-dependencies-from-debian-control/211319#211319
dpkg-buildpackage
dpkg -i ../<package-name-version>.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Install to a different local path and write a `postinst` script to create the directory in `/usr/local` and copy the files there.

As you can imagine, this probably violates both the letter and the spirit of the Debian policy. But it's your network, your rules, your users (and their easily discoverable workarounds).

For better usability, you could mark these files as conffiles so that at least they will be removed if you purge the package, but stay if you merely uninstall it.

Bottom line, files `dpkg` doesn't know about, it cannot remove.