# equivs-build / apt-get: how to preserve directory

Tags: debian, package-management

I'm building some packages for a private repository using `equivs-build`. The files are installing ok using `apt-get install` but when I go to remove them they are trying to delete the whole folder structure they are installed to.

In the equivs file I have the line:

```
Files: <file to copy> /usr/local/sbin/
```

When I run `apt-get remove` there are messages about

> '.. directory /usr/local not empty so not removed.'

The `/usr/local/sbin` folder is removed.

Is there some way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few references to this on *Stackoverflow* in the context of using `dpkg` which is the underlying tool behind `apt-get`: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704354/dpkg-warning-while-removing-directory-usr-local-not-empty-so-not-removed), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786308/dpkg-giving-error-is-a-directory?rq=1) an [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122820/building-a-deb-of-a-python-project-fails-dpkg-buildpackage-is-trying-to-delet?rq=1). And every time the same considerations come up:

1. It is a **warning** only and the package was indeed removed with its directory as requested
2. In terms of **best practices**, one shouldn't use /usr/local for packages because of [Debian policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html) (what does [lintian](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/lintian) say about the package?)and to respect the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY)
3. Some people experience a **different behavior** with the exact same removal operation when the target is elsewhere i.e. /bin VS. /usr/local/bin and even /opt
4. preinst, prerm, postinst, and postrm **scripts** can technically contain things that alter the behavior during install/remove - but then again is the behavior of dpkg in /usr/local an exception or the rule (the removal of empty top directories, not limited to one level) - and is the design affected by package and folder ownership or just by the package being in /usr/local?

Finally, there might be **alternatives** which involve a better structuring of the task at hand as it expands in time... for instance creating a [package repository](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.setup-apt-package-repository.html). Ultimately [equivs-build](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.building-first-package.html) has to be used in a way which doesn't [conflict](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86176/equivs-enhance-or-update-an-existing-package-without-uninstalling) with the design of the package management system.

Comment: When I say a "warning only" I mean that the package was indeed removed - it wasn't a showstopper. I understand that sbin was removed also. Maybe leaving a dummy file there would prevent this but that's not very elegant loll.

Comment: I will ultimately have a number of packages in a private repository. Each will have its own versioning and be maintained by puppet. My understanding of linux-lore is that '/usr/local/<*>' was intended for user applications. Not to be confused with '/bin' or '/sbin'.

Comment: Well - total hack - putting a 'place holder' file in there prevented `apt-get remove <package>` from removing the folder. I must not be using this properly.

Comment: Haha, beginner's luck on my part with the "place holder" file advice. Afterwards I thought why not just a directory? I had much less luck trying to replicate the behavior you were describing, as I made a mistake in the header file generated by `equivs-control` trying to set up my own package...  I entered a name+version combo as the package _name_ instead of just the name... then `dh_make` didn't work etc. But yeah, that topic is all very interesting! Happy this was helpful!

Comment: see also the [postrm hack](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215300/120177) from [an example stub source package](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/ca-certificates.git/tree/examples/ca-certificates-local/README) that includes a dummy CA
certificate in the /usr/local/share/ca-certificates directory

Answer (score 1):

Does your `Files` line look as you typed it or are you missing the colon (`:`) after the word `Files`?

As in this example, equivs control file:

```
### Commented entries have reasonable defaults.
### Uncomment to edit them.
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.6.2

Package: main-package
Version: 0.0.1
Maintainer: Your Name <a.spam.box@mail.sj>
# Pre-Depends: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Depends: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Recommends: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Suggests: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Provides: <comma-separated list of packages>
# Replaces: <comma-separated list of packages>
Architecture: all
# Copyright: <copyright file; defaults to GPL2>
# Changelog: <changelog file; defaults to a generic changelog>
# Readme: <README.Debian file; defaults to a generic one>
Files: /home/myuser/main-package.conf /etc/main-package.conf
Description: <short description; defaults to some wise words>
 long description and info
```

#### References

- [Howto: create "configuration packages" with equivs](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=726317)

Comment: My mistake - it does read as 'Files: <file to copy> /usr/local/sbin/<file>'. I edited the question to reflect this.