# How to quickly create a local apt repository for random packages using a Debian based linux distribution?

Tags: debian, package-management, apt

Some situations call for manually installing a local package using `dpkg -i <packagename>`. Sometimes it may be further useful to leverage the functionality of `apt` with that package so the question is:

How do you quickly create a local repository for random packages using a Debian based linux distribution - like Xubuntu 13.04/Ubuntu?

Comment: Just FYI. The usual thing is to follow `dpkg -i <packagename>` with `apt-get -f install` to pull in required packages. Also, the usual thing to create an apt repos for Debian is reprepro.

Comment: I've found reprepro helpful

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @Faheem Mitha: can you please briefly expand on why running `apt` with `--fix-broken` would be required after installing a local package with `dpkg -i`? Wouldn't dpkg take care of that? I [read](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) it may be required the first time apt is run? @FM&Gilles: About [reprepro](https://wiki.debian.org/SettingUpSignedAptRepositoryWithReprepro). Seems useful if I could get it to work (not sure about dir struct, contents of 3 files or params at runtime). Will try again and update or post full question.

Comment: @illuminÉ : `dpkg` does not resolve dependencies, but `apt` does. `dpkg` will warn of broken dependencies, but is low level, so will not attempt to fix them. The `dpkg -i *.deb` followed by `apt-get -f install` is standard procedure. There is a wishlist bug to have `apt` itself handle the case of local package installation, and there is even a patch, I think, but it has not yet been implemented. See [apt-get install could install local package files, too](http://bugs.debian.org/47379), originally filed in 1999.

Comment: @illuminÉ Expressing interest in this feature will not hurt. I think the more people who (politely) express interest, the more likely it is that it will be implemented. Note also that gdebi is an alternative, as noted in the bug report. That is part of the reason it has not been implemented, I think. Though having such core functionality part of apt would be better than having this functionality as part of another package.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha : thank you for making it clear. I am inexperienced and when I poked at [equivs-build](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86176/equivs-enhance-or-update-an-existing-package-without-uninstalling) I had noticed some differences in the way `apt` behaves vs. `dpkg` but both had refused to install something in my scenario so I didn't make anything of it. I also read the wishlist bug. I wonder how it would be implemented i.e. would the dir where the .deb is be "padded" like reprepro does with all the config and dir structure or would the .deb be simply be brought to cache etc.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: Also, thanks for the tip on [gdebi](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/gdebi.1.html)! In the end I have a hard time really understanding why from a design perspective such tools "expose" so many features whereas `dpkg` is pretty "stoic" yet doesn't seem to be a bottleneck?! Does it mean that technically apt could be managing many types of lower level installers like dpkg? Why were the features of apt and dpkg split in the fashion you described when both are maintained by Debian? Anyways, Debian's packaging is all quite interesting.

Comment: @illuminÉ: `dpkg` handles low level installation features, `apt` handles higher level issue like dependency resolution. This is by design. It is for reasons of modularity and flexibility. While `dpkg` is the only game in town for low level, there are alternatives to `apt-get` for high level, namely `aptitude` and there is something called `dselect` which now few people use but was once the standard. Ultimately, all the high level tools manipulate the dpkg system. I don't know anything about gdebi. I'm also not really familar with apt internals, so will not speculate about that.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This should be distinguished from the situation where you're trying to [replicate a full package tree](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository) from an official repository and [fine tuning sources priority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135339/assign-highest-priority-to-my-local-repository). Random packages mean virtual packages, packages which are compiled locally or copied in a piecemeal fashion for testing purposes. Here's a simple setup based on now [obsolete documentation](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-basico.en.html#s-dpkg-scanpackages).

First, make a directory to host the packages:

```
mkdir <packagedir>
```

Then move your .deb package files there. Execute this command from the directory above the one we just created (make sure permissions allow this!):

```
dpkg-scanpackages packagedir | gzip > packagedir/Packages.gz
```

Now create a file with extension `.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` with the contents:

```
deb [trusted=yes] file:///path_to_dir_above_packagedir packagedir/
```

and update the apt database:

```
apt-get update
```

At this point the packages in our local repository can be installed like any other package using `apt-get install <packagename>`. When new packages are added to the local repository, the prescribed `dpkg-scanpackages` command must be issued again to update the *Packages.gz* file and `apt` must be updated before the new packages are made available. Hopefully this can be useful for [testing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86176/equivs-enhance-or-update-an-existing-package-without-uninstalling) purposes.

Comment: With the new apt 1.1, one needs `[trusted=yes]` between `deb` and the `file:///` URI (see the `sources.list(5)` man page), otherwise `apt-get update` fails because of the lack of signature.

Answer (score 6):

Though [a similar answer already exist](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87131/66803) and [several similar answers are there on AU](https://askubuntu.com/q/170348/256099) also, I am posting this answer to recommend the use of `apt-ftparchive` instead of `dpkg-scanpackages`

#### Why `apt-ftparchive` instead of `dpkg-scanpackages`?

- `dpkg-scanpackages` command is provided by `dpkg-dev` package which doesn't come with installation image of distribution, as per my observation, it may not be installed on your machine. You will first need to install `dpkg-dev` package to avail the `dpkg-scanpackages` command. And the aim of setting up local repository is usually to manage software packages offline on a machine which is not connected to the internet. **Whereas** `apt-ftparchive` command is provided by `apt-utils` which comes with the usual installation image of the distribution. So, you don't need to install any extra packages.
- Since we are about to do package-management using apt instead of dpkg, why not to use apt for scanning packages also? :)

---

#### How to setup APT local repository?

**Step 1:** Create a directory in which you'll put your debs.

```
$ mkdir ~/apt-local-repository
```

**Step 2:** Add your local directory to the top of repositories' list at `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
$ head -n 1 /etc/apt/sources.list
deb [trusted=yes] file:/home/pandya/apt-local-repository/ ./
```

- Note that if you don't set `[trusted=yes]`, you'll need to set `--allow-unauthenticated` argument while installing packages through `apt`.
- The line is added to the top of repositories' list to give it the highest priority. If you add it to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` instead, apt will try to install it from online repository (as defined at `/etc/apt/sources.list`), giving your local repository the less priority.

**Step 3**: Put your debs to `~/apt-local-repository`

**Step 4**: Indexing package list using `aptftparchive`

```
$ cd ~/apt-local-repository/; apt-ftparchive packages . > Packages
```

**Step 5**: Update the apt index/database using `sudo apt update`

*Done*. Now you can install your deb package using `sudo apt install <packagename>`. Just repeat steps 3 to 5 every-time you change your local database.

---

Useful tips:

- You can run `apt-cache policy <packagename>` to investigate whether APT is recognizing your local deb package and giving it the highest priority
- You can run `sudo apt-get --print-uris install <packagename>` to check whether all dependencies are satisfied or you need to download any extra packages. Also it will list urls which would be i) ftp:// for packages you have in your local repository and/or ii) http:// for packages or missing dependencies required to be downloaded from Internet.

You may have a look at one script called [**L**ocal **A**pt **R**epository **M**anager](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deep-Pandya/larm/master/larm) I have created.

Comment: thanks for useful tips

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a repo with the full structure that you need for tools like debootstrap, the simplest way I've found is:

1. Create a repository directory.

   ```
   # mkdir -p /opt/debian/conf
   ```
2. Create an `/opt/debian/conf/distributions` file with contents like this (adjust as appropriate for the distribution you're using):

   ```
   Label: Local APT repository
   Codename: jessie
   Architectures: amd64
   Components: main
   Description: Local APT repository for debootstrap
   ```
3. Import your package with `reprepro`:

   ```
   # reprepro -b /opt/debian includedeb jessie /path/to/package.db
   ```
4. Import a bunch of packages with a shell for-loop,
   e.g.. everything from your APT cache:

   ```
   # cd /var/cache/apt/archives
   # for DEB in *.deb
   do
       reprepro -b /opt/debian includedeb jessie "$DEB"
   done
   ```

This will create an unsigned archive. 
It can be used with debootstrap with the `--no-check-gpg` option.