# How to stop `apt-get` complaining about unmet dependencies when I manually install the software from source?

Tags: debian, apt

I have been installing some applications onto my Debian system. Now there are some that have dependencies that I do not want installed with the applications at the moment. I have managed this by using `dpkg` in some cases. The installed applications work fine without them at the moment.

But now, every time I use `apt-get`, it complains about unmet dependencies.

How do I cheat `apt-get` into thinking that all dependencies (2-3) are installed? Is there some file I can edit?

Comment: /etc/apt/preferences has a version preferences file which allows  "pinning", i.e. a preference to get certain packages from a separate source or from a different version of a distribution. You might be able to specify a null address there.

Comment: I remember having all sorts of difficulties with creating virtual packages in a [different yet related](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86176/equivs-enhance-or-update-an-existing-package-without-uninstalling/86251) scenario. It can be daunting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `equivs` tool to create dummy Debian packages to satisfy dependencies. The documentation provides the following steps:

```
cd /tmp
equivs-control ns-control  # or cp /usr/share/doc/equivs/examples/<a control file> ns-control
# edit ns-control
equivs-build ns-control
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/ns-dummy_1.0_all.deb
```

In the step “edit ns-control”, the only field in the file that needs to be edited is the `Package:` field, to specify which package you are creating a dummy for.

If there is a Debian package which has a package declared as a Dependency but still runs, you should file a bug report. If the extra packages are "Recommends", then you should install the package with the following:

```
apt-get --no-install-recommends install foo
```

Comment: Awesome.  Better than my "you could do it like this", but without the how.  Deleting my answer.