# How to install / parse build dependencies from debian/control?

Tags: debian, package-management, packaging

Let's suppose you downloaded a source code folder, that contains an existing `/debian/` folder as well as `/debian/control` file.

Let's suppose the package in question is not in Debian official repository, so `apt-get build-dep` cannot be used.

How to parse the `Build-Depends:` line?

For example, if the line would read `Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 8), faketime`, is there some tool `control-parse debian/control build-depends` that would echo `debhelper faketime`?

Especially when it's multi line?

Are there existing Debian tools or has one to write its own code to parse this?

Answer (score 10):

**Parsing:**

Use modules from the `libdpkg-perl` (`dpkg-checkbuilddeps` uses those modules internally)

Add the following lines to `print-build-deps` and run `print-build-deps` at the source package root.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Dpkg::Control::Info;
use Dpkg::Deps;

my $control = Dpkg::Control::Info->new();
my $fields = $control->get_source();
my $build_depends = deps_parse($fields->{'Build-Depends'});
print deps_concat($build_depends) . "\n";
```

See also:

```
perldoc Dpkg::Control::Info
perldoc Dpkg::Deps
```

**Installation:**

You can use `mk-build-deps` from `devscripts`:

```
apt-get install devscripts
apt-get install equivs
cd project-root # project-root contains debian/control
mk-build-deps -i
```

`man mk-build-deps` says:

```
mk-build-deps - build a package satisfying a package's build-dependencies
-i, --install
       Install the generated packages and its build-dependencies
```

Comment: This seems like a clean solution because it uses tools from the context, so it might be more robust. On recent Debian (at least) it needs packages `devscripts` **and** `equivs`, generate a temp package `myproject-build-deps` and installs it. This is nice if you're not intending to keep the build-time dependencies on your machine: just uninstall `devscripts`, `equivs` and `myproject-build-deps`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `dpkg-checkbuilddeps`. The man page says

> This program checks the installed packages in the system against the
>   build dependencies and build conflicts listed in the control file. If
>   any
>          are not met, it displays them and exits with a nonzero return code.

For example:

```
faheem@orwell:/usr/local/src/julia/julia-0.3.2$ dpkg-checkbuilddeps
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: libopenblas-dev (>= 0.2.10-1~) libopenlibm-dev libopenspecfun-dev (>= 0.4~) patchelf python-sphinx-rtd-theme
```

However, you could also just try building the package, using (for example) `debuild`, e.g.

```
faheem@orwell:/usr/local/src/julia/julia-0.3.2$ debuild -uc -us
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: source package julia
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.3.2-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Sébastien Villemot <sebastien@debian.org>
 dpkg-source --before-build julia-0.3.2
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: libopenblas-dev (>= 0.2.10-1~) libopenlibm-dev libopenspecfun-dev (>= 0.4~) patchelf python-sphinx-rtd-theme
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
debuild: fatal error at line 1357:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

Which gives the same information (since it uses `dpkg-checkbuilddeps`), but is a little noisier.

Comment: `dpkg-checkbuilddeps` outputs only unmet build dependencies. See my [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211319/120177) about parsing in common case.

Answer (score 3):

This Perl one-liner can be used to parse building dependencies from `debian/control`:

```
perl -ne 'next if /^#/; $p=(s/^Build-Depends:\s*/ / or (/^ / and $p)); s/,|\n|\([^)]+\)//mg; print if $p' < debian/control
```

or runtime deps for built packages:

```
perl -ne 'next if /^#/; $p=(s/^Depends:\s*/ / or (/^ / and $p)); s/,|\n|\([^)]+\)//mg; print if $p' < debian/control
```

Comment: Thanks to this one-lined, installing parsed dependencies is as easy as `apt-get install $(perl -ne 'next if /^#/; $p=(s/^Build-Depends:\s*/ / or (/^ / and $p)); s/,|\n|\([^)]+\)//mg; print if $p' < debian/control)'`. Just be aware that the dependencies will be marked as manually installed, so they will stick in the build environment. This has no importance in a throwaway build environment (chroot, docker), but if you build in your regular environment the build-time dependencies packages will remain. They can be quite big for some packages.