# Should I add certificates to /usr/share/ca-certificates?

Tags: ubuntu, certificates, puppet

I try to automate to adding a certificate on an Ubuntu server 14.04 with puppet or a one liner command.

I added certificates manually with these commands :

```
mkdir  /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra
cp toto.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/toto.crt
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

I tried the command : update-ca-certificates but it didn't update my /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.

I tried too the command : sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates (with and without the option -f noninteractive) but i can't to accept all my certificates automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [How do you add a certification authority to ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu) you should copy to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` (note `local`) not `/usr/share/ca-certificates/extra`.

Comment: or you can create a package that includes a certificate:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215300/120177 , upload this package to your local repo, and install with `apt-get`